# Which nation on Earth has been under foreign rule the longest?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, ancient-egypt, contemporary-history

The Philippines was under Spanish rule for over 333 years. After the Battle of Manila Bay and the Treaty of Paris (1898), rule of the Philippines was transferred from Spain to the USA.

From a brief period between 1942-1945, the Philippines was under Japanese rule. The Americans officially granted independence to the Philippines in 1946.

If we add it all up, the Philippines was under foreign rule for almost 400 years.

Is there any other nation on Earth that had been under foreign rule longer?

Comment: Depends on how you define 'foreign', probably. I could make the argument that Israel was under foreign rule from 70 to 1948, or that parts of America have been under foreign rule since the 17th century.

Comment: This is too political, and I have voted to close.

Comment: @Avi : if a nation effectively disappears or its territory is permanently absorbed into that of another, it probably does not meet the criteria of this (unclear) question.

Comment: Seems like the Kurdish nation might be a good fit. Did they ever have a state of their own? Yet I see the Kurds as a "nation", not an "ethnic minority".

Comment: England has been ruled by monarchs with Danish, French, Scottish and German origin (including the present dynasty)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question & should not be closed. We can get all pedantic about 'nation','foreign' etc. but it is clear what Ian is asking & it is an interesting question related to history.

Comment: The question doesn't contain stable theoretical terms and this is troll bait.

Comment: @Abhilash It sounds tempting but unless viewed neutrally it is very hard to define "foreign" and "national".

Comment: @Abhilash - The question certainly has potential, but as it stands it is quite unclear what is meant by "nation" and "foreign rule", and what time periods are to be considered. I have posted an answer that contains **numerous** references which may or may not be valid, depending on how these terms are defined. For example - Ancient Egypt was ruled for over 500 years by the Greeks and Romans, but there were short periods of revolt and instablity which might increase this total perhaps to 600 years if we ignore them - do they interrupt the reckoning of "foreign rule"?

Comment: @SamuelRussell - I see a question with terms that are not clearly defined. I do not see "troll bait". Do you believe the poster is trying to garner some special sympathy for the Philippines, or intends to create a platform for someone to rant on about the abuses of colonialism?

Comment: It's hard to define this even if you are neutral. Gotland has been under foreign rule for 1500 years or so. Most people would laugh if you say that and go "what, foreign? Gotland is a part of Sweden". So at some point the foreign rule becomes non-foreign just by virtue of have been going on long enough. So this is not answerable.

Comment: @Vector, claims about the specific oppression of imaginary national communities are handy troll bait.  To accuse my own imaginary national community: Australia wasn't formed in 1788.  The intense role of the imaginary past to nations, particularly the claim that modern cultural communities have an eternal connection to land or past peoples who lived there is why this is troll bait.  "X is was and always will be Y.  As can be clearly seen from the 742 year oppression of Ys living under X."

Comment: @SamuelRussell - I understand where you're going, but IMO you are reading too much into this question. For one, there is no mention of "oppression" at all. Had there been, I would have "smelled" exactly what you are "smelling" and would not have dealt with the question at all. Perhaps being "down under" you know more about contemporary politics in the Philippines than I (not hard considering I know nothing...) and have good reason to believe there is a political agenda behind the question.

Comment: I think Vector is right, this question is just a victim of the normal discourse about "nations" and "nation states" as if these are things that actually exist.

Answer (score 10):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "nation" and "foreign rule," and if your question is "what is the longest" or, is there a place that was under foreign rule longer than the Philippines.

But - we have several places, according to what appear to be your criteria, that were under foreign rule longer than the 333 years you cite for the Philippines, although not all of them as as long as the total for the Philippines if you include also American and Japanese rule:

> [Goa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa) is a former Portuguese province; the Portuguese overseas
> territory of Portuguese India existed for about 450 years until it was
> annexed by India in 1961.
>
> [Parts of New Guinea, which has a complicated history:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Guinea#European_contact)
>
> The first European contact with New Guinea was by Portuguese and
> Spanish sailors in the 16th century. In 1526-27 the Portuguese
> explorer Jorge de Meneses saw the western tip of New Guinea and named
> it ilhas dos Papuas. In 1528 Spanish navigator Álvaro de Saavedra also
> recorded its sighting when trying to return from Tidore to New Spain.
> In 1545 the Spaniard Íñigo Ortíz de Retes sailed along the north coast
> of New Guinea as far as the Mamberamo River near which he landed on 20
> June, naming the island 'Nueva Guinea'.[35] The first map showing the
> whole island (as an island) was published in 1600 and shows it as
> 'Nova Guinea'. In 1606 Luís Vaz de Torres explored the southern coast
> of New Guinea from Milne Bay to the Gulf of Papua including Orangerie
> Bay which he named Bahía de San Lorenzo. His expedition also
> discovered Basilaki Island naming it Tierra de San Buenaventura, which
> he claimed for Spain in July 1606.[36] On October 18 his expedition
> reached the western part of the island in present-day Indonesia, and
> also claimed the territory for the King of Spain.
>
> Another candidate might be [Inner Mongolia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_Mongolia)
>
> The eastern Mongol tribes near and in Manchuria, particularly the
> Khorchin and Southern Khalkha in today's Inner Mongolia intermarried,
> formed alliances with, and fought against the Jurchen tribes until
> Nurhaci, the founder of the new Jin Dynasty, consolidated his control
> over all groups in the area in 1593...
>
> [Indonesia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia#History)  Following three and a half centuries of Dutch
> colonialism, Indonesia secured its independence after World War II.

*(Wiki is apparently calculating from 1602 when the Dutch East India Company became the dominant force in Indonesia until 1949, when Indonesia finally achieved complete independence from the Dutch.)*

So here you have three or more places which might meet your criteria. But if you look carefully over the map I am certain there are more places, depending on your exact criteria, **particularly islands in the Pacific, the Mediterranean and the East and West Indies.**

Consider for example [Autonomous Region of the Azores (under Portuguese administration)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Azores)

> One (unproven) hypothesis is that the Azores were discovered in the
> course of a 1341 mapping expedition to the Canary Islands, sponsored
> by King Afonso IV of Portugal and commanded by the Florentine
> Angiolino del Tegghia de Corbizzi and the Genoese Nicoloso da
> Recco. Although not quite described in the 1341 report, Madeira
> and the Azores might nonetheless have been seen from a distance on the
> expedition's return via a long sailing arc (volta do mar) from the
> Canary islands.[16] Even if not discovered by the 1341 mapping
> expedition itself, the islands may have been found by any of the
> numerous Majorcan expeditions that were launched into the Atlantic
> Ocean in the aftermath, destined for slaving runs on the newly-mapped
> Canary islands. Nonetheless, regardless of who sighted them in the
> 14th century, there seems to have been no follow-up until **the 15th century**.

[Autonomous Region of the Madeira (under Portuguese administration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira)

> Madeira was discovered by Portuguese sailors in the service of Infante
> D. Henrique (Henry the Navigator) in 1419, **and settled after 1420**. The
> archipelago is considered to be the first territorial discovery of the
> exploratory period of the Portuguese Age of Discovery.

[Canary Islands -  one of Spain's 17 autonomous communities:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_Islands)

> There may have been a Portuguese expedition that attempted to colonize
> the islands as early as 1336, but there is not enough hard evidence to
> support this. **In 1402, the Castilian conquest of the islands began**,
> with the expedition of French explorers Jean de Béthencourt and
> Gadifer de la Salle, nobles and vassals of Henry III of Castile, to
> Lanzarote. From there, they conquered Fuerteventura (1405) and El
> Hierro. Béthencourt received the title King of the Canary Islands, but
> still recognized King Henry III as his overlord.

[British Virgin Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Virgin_Islands) are (today still) a British overseas
territory:

> The Dutch established a permanent settlement on the island of Tortola by 1648. In 1672, the English captured Tortola from the Dutch, and the English annexation of Anegada and Virgin Gorda followed in 1680. Meanwhile, over the period 1672–1733, the Danish gained control of the nearby islands of Saint Thomas, Saint John and Saint Croix.

Depending on how one calculates, the British Virgin Islands might be considered "under foreign rule" for over 350 years.

***In medieval and ancient times, we have more examples to consider, for example:***

[Gaul - today France:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaul)

> **Roman control of Gaul lasted for five centuries,** until the last Roman
> rump state, the Domain of Soissons, fell to the Franks in AD 486

[Roman Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Britain)

> Roman Britain, referred to by the Romans as Britannia, was the part of
> the island of Great Britain controlled by the Roman Empire **from 43 AD until c. 410.**

[Ancient Egypt, under the Greeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Ptolemaic_Egypt) [and Romans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegyptus_%28province%29) was ruled by these two powers continuously **from  323 BC until at least 269 AD, a period of well over 500 years.** (However, as Lennart Regebro has pointed out in the comments, it is debatable if the Ptolemaic Kingdom constituted an extension and continuation of the Greek Empire, or it was an Egyptian entity, the result of usurpation of the Egyptian throne by the Greek Ptolemies - see the comments regarding this):

> The Ptolemaic Kingdom (/ˌtɒləˈmeɪ.ɪk/; Greek: Πτολεμαϊκὴ βασιλεία,
> Ptolemaïkḕ Basileía)[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa) was a Hellenistic kingdom in Egypt. It was
> ruled by the Ptolemaic dynasty that Ptolemy I Soter founded after the
> death of Alexander the Great in 323 BC—which ended with the death of
> Cleopatra VII and the Roman conquest in 30 BC...
>
> The Roman province of Egypt (Latin: Aegyptus, pronounced
> [ai̯ˈgyp.tus]; Greek: Αἴγυπτος Aigyptos [ɛ́ːɣyptos]) was established
> in 30 BC after Octavian (the future emperor Augustus) defeated his
> rival Mark Antony, deposed his lover Queen Cleopatra VII and annexed
> the Ptolemaic kingdom of Egypt to the Roman Empire. The province
> encompassed most of modern-day Egypt except for the Sinai Peninsula
> (which would later be conquered by Trajan).
>
> Zenobia, queen of Palmyra, took the country away from the Romans when
> she conquered Aegyptus in 269, declaring herself the Queen of Egypt
> also....

[Transylvania (now consolidated into Romania):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transylvania#Hungarian_rule)

> **Between 1003 and 1526,** Transylvania was a voivodeship of the Kingdom
> of Hungary, led by a voivode appointed by the Hungarian King.

[**Perhaps** Albania (Investigate also other nations in far eastern Europe who were ruled by the Ottomans for long periods of time - they may also be candidates):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albania#Ottoman_Period)

> The Ottomans erected their garrisons throughout southern Albania by
> 1415 and **established formal jurisdiction over most of Albania by
> 1431....Albania remained under Ottoman control as part of the Rumelia province until 1912, when the first independent Albanian state was
> declared.**

***Conclusion:***

**Clearly, although the Philippines was indeed under "foreign rule" for a long period of time, it cannot lay claim to the dubious distinction of having *the longest* such period. Of all the examples cited, IMO *Egypt*, *Gaul,* and *Transylvania* might best qualify as the "longest," all in the neighborhood of 500 years, being quite clearly defined geographic areas with fairly homogeneous, indigenous populations that were conquered and ruled continuously by arguably true nation-states in the modern sense. In the modern era, *Goa* is probably the best example**

**But we could go on, depending on your time parameters, and definitions of "nation", and "foreign rule", which is why your question has been closed.**

Comment: With the type of definition of "nation" you seem to use, I give you Finland: From at least 1249 to 1809 part of Sweden, from 1809 to 1917 part of Russia. Minimum 668 years. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro - could be. Obviously the definition of "nation" is problematic in the question itself. What was going in the Philippines before the Spaniards came in? Islamic rule, tribes, etc. If we wanted to to we could probably include every place on earth. In my conclusion I did try to go with fairly well defined "nations" that were conquered by other fairly well defined "nations". The question is, was there a Finnish "nation" that was taken over by the Swedes, or just a group of indigenious people called "Finns". But agreed, Finland is probably no worse than some of my examples.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - I think Egypt being ruled by the Greeks and Romans is the best example up there of a clearly defined nation that was ruled by other clearly defined nations.

Comment: Calling the Ptolemaic rule "foreign" though means that England has been under foreign rule since the dark ages, when Anglo-saxons arrived. And that's assuming the time between roman rule and anglo-saxon was by English guys. It's not actually ruled by a foreign power, it's just that the rulers are foreign.

Comment: @LennartRegebro ""not actually ruled by a foreign power, just that the rulers are foreign"-this is an excellent point, although IMO it's not quite that clear. I see that Ptolemy I Soter was one of Alexander's potential successors, and conquered Egypt as a Greek general, afterwards making himself Pharoah, bringing Greek culture and language to Egypt. So the Ptolemaic Kingdom was a sort of extension of Greece. Then Rome "annexed the Ptolemaic kingdom of Egypt to the Roman Empire." That says to me that it was already considered "Greek Territory" and therefore Rome's natural legacy.

Comment: "So the Ptolemaic Kingdom was a sort of extension of Greece" - Not in any other way than England was an extension of Scandinavia or France, or China an extension of Mongolia.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - I think not.  Ptolemaic Kingdom was a temporary set-up. Eventually it broke up and became Rome and then Egypt once again. So it was just a little incursion of the Greeks and Romans into Egypt.

Comment: You don't seem to contradict anything I said, which I take as you now agreeing with me. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10423/discussion-between-vector-and-lennart-regebro)

Comment: I'm pretty surprised nobody mentioned Italy, which for the most part was under foreign rule from the fall of the Roman Empire to the late 19th century.

Comment: @LennartRegebro : same for Transylvania. It sounds quite silly to name 1003-1526 as "foreign rule". With the same logic, one could say "1920-today" as "foreign rule" if looked at it from the other side. Besides, Transylvania was not a nation in the Middle Ages. It actually became one for some time in the 16th and 17t centuries.